# Autocomplete textbox in ASP.NET Core not working

Tags: asp.net-core, text, autocomplete

```
@model InventoryManagement.Models.ViewModel.AddBom
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
}

<div class="bg-secondary bg-opacity-10 py-2">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            Add BOM
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container py-5">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Item Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemname" asp-for="Itemlist" />
        </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 @section Scripts
 {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var kk = function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Bom/AutoComplete/',
                    data: { "prefix": request.term },
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var formattedData = $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.val
                            };
                        });
                        response(formattedData);
                        console.log("888", formattedData)
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            };
                 console.log("888hh", kk);
                 $("#itemname").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    kk(request, response);
                    alert("llllllllllllllllllllll");
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    //get selected value
                    //$("#personNameValue").val(i.item.val);
                },
          
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is the `Add.cshtml` file. Here the `success` function is working and `console.log` is outputting value, but the value is not displaying in dropdown.

This is the `Bomcontroller.cs` and is correctly fetching values:

```
[HttpPost("AutoComplete")]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
{
    var persons = (from item in this.jobdbcontext.ItemMaster
                   where item.itemname.StartsWith(prefix)
                   select new
                       {
                           label = item.itemname,
                           val = item.itemid
                       }).Take(5).ToList();

    return Json(persons);
}
```

Comment: Do you use `F12` to see if any error message ? "but the value is not displaying in dropdown." What's your dropdown ?

Comment: console.log output is showing value  in console window 
{label: 'Item1', val: 'Item1'}
label
: 
"Item1"
val
: 
"Item1"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
Bom:281 
{label: 'Item2', val: 'Item2'}
label
: 
"Item2"
val
: 
"Item2"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
Bom:281 
{label: 'Item3', val: 'Item3'}
label
: 
"Item3"
val
: 
"Item3"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

1.Change the `[HttpPost("AutoComplete")]` to `[HttpPost]`

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
  {...//add your code}
```

2.Modify your script code like below **OR** just remove  `alert("llllllllllllllllllllll");` from your code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#itemname").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Bom/AutoComplete',
                    data: { "prefix": request.term },
                    type: "POST",                        
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.label, value: item.val };
                        }))    
                    }    
                })
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: with [HttpPost("AutoComplete")] only it is redirecting to controller and is properly fetching values .  output in coming on success function of ajax ..but value is not displaying in dropdown

Comment: Now it is working fine. Because of breakpoint it is  taking time to display